# Why do I keep getting the same output in this problem?

Tags: c

C
What is that that I'm doing wrong?I'm trying to print for the different months with dates their corresponding seasons But I keep getting the first (printf) for all of them which is Winter.

dates for each season are:
Spring: March 20 - June 20
Summer: June 21 - September 21
Autumn: September 22 - December 20
Winter: December 21 - March 19

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>


int main(void) {
    char inputMonth[50];
    int inputDay;

    scanf("%s", inputMonth);
    scanf("%d", & inputDay);

    /* Type your code here. */
    //winter
    if (strcmp(inputMonth, "December") && (21 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 30)) {
        printf("Winter\n");
    } else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "January") && (1 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 31)) {
        printf("Winter\n");
    } else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "February") && (1 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 29)) {
        printf("Winter\n");
    } else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "March") && (1 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 19)) {
        printf("Winter\n");
    }
    //spring
    else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "March") && (20 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 31)) {
        printf("Spring\n");
    } else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "April") && (1 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 31)) {
        printf("Spring\n");
    } else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "May") && (1 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 30)) {
        printf("Spring\n");
    } else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "June") && (1 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 20)) {
        printf("Spring\n");
    }
    //summer
    else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "June") && (21 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 31)) {
        printf("Summer\n");
    } else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "July") && (1 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 31)) {
        printf("Summer\n");
    } else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "August") && (1 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 31)) {
        printf("%sSummer\n");
    } else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "September") && (1 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 21)) {
        printf("Summer\n");
    }
    //autumn
    else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "September") && (22 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 30)) {
        printf("Autumn\n");
    } else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "October") && (1 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 31)) {
        printf("Autumn\n");
    } else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "November") && (1 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 30)) {
        printf("Autumn\n");
    } else if (strcmp(inputMonth, "December") && (1 <= inputDay && inputDay <= 20)) {
        printf("Autumn\n");
    } else {
        printf("Invalid\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input you are entering so that others can try to reproduce it?

Comment: Ex: If the input is:

April 11

the output is:

Spring

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why is strcmp not working in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990141/why-is-strcmp-not-working-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

`strcmp(inputMonth, "December")`

This returns true if inputMonth is different from December.

strcmp just returns a negative value,0 or a positive value if the first is less than/equal to/greater than the second argument. So, if both strings are the same, strcmp() returns 0.

If you wish to check for `"December"` then you need **!strcmp()**

Thus,
`if (!strcmp(inputMonth, "December"))`

Comment: correction noted in the answer.