# Why does this strcmp not trigger true?

Tags: c, strcmp

I am trying to make a shell program and am working on mkdir, I am reading in the user input and breaking it into segments using sscanf and then trying to use strcmp to check if the first word was "mkdir", the strcmp works if I leave the stdin as is without using sscanf. Can someone tell me why it doesn't work like this, and how to fix it?
Thanks,

```
//#include "parser.c"
#include <stdio.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifndef MAX_BUF
#define MAX_BUF 200
#endif

int main(void)
{
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter a command: ");
        char input[20];
        char line[4][20];
        fgets(input, 20, stdin);
        sscanf(input, "%s %s", line[0], line[1]);
        if(strcmp(line[0], "mkdir")) {
            char path[MAX_BUF];
            getcwd(path, MAX_BUF);
            strcat(path, "/");
            strcat(path, line[1]);
            mkdir(path, 0700);
            printf(path);
        }
        
    
        //printf("output %s", input);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try strcmp(line[0], "mkdir") == 0 because strcmp(a,b) returns <0 if a < b, 0 if a == b, and >0 otherwise (see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html ). Eg: strcmp returns 0 in your case, and the if condition evaluate to false.

Comment: If a function doesn't return what you expect, the first step is to check the function documentation for its return value specification

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why is strcmp not working in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990141/why-is-strcmp-not-working-in-c)

Comment: that's not how you check `strcmp` result https://stackoverflow.com/q/69308112/995714

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your expression:

```c
strcmp(line[0], "mkdir")
```

into:

```c
strcmp(line[0], "mkdir") == 0
```

A match returns zero<sup>(a)</sup> which, when treated as a boolean, is *false* rather than true. In other words, your `if` is currrenly firing for anything *other* than `mkdir`.

---

There are a few other problems with your code, such as its inability to create directories longer than about thirteen characters (buffer size twenty minus one for the `'\0'` minus six for the `"mkdir "`), and the fact `line[1]` will be some arbitrary value if you were to just type in `mkdir` on its own. That won't end well :-)

You could get around that last one by checking to ensure the correct number of things were scanned, with something like:

```c
if (sscanf(input, "%s %s", line[0], line[1]) != 2) {
    output_some_error();
} else {
    your_current_processing_of_line1_and_line2();
}
```

The general rule is: if a failure can affect your ability to proceed safely, you should probably check for, and act on, that failure.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The call `strcmp(a, b)` will return a value as per the following table:

| Situation: | a < b | a == b | a > b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Returns: | < 0 | 0 | > 0 |
| Boolean equivalent: | true | false | true |